# php session cart recording item quantity twice using insert

Tags: php, mysql, session, foreach, insert

When I run the below code with a cart that has 1 item `$_SESSION['cart']` contains several fields: id, title, qty etc.. with a qty set to 1, It always doubles the qty subtracted from current inventory qty.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $result){
 $insert  = 'UPDATE collateral SET stock = stock - '.$result['qty'].' WHERE id = '.$result['id'];
 mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

So when this runs with the above item and current inventory for that item is 400, the result leaves me with 398.

Can't for the life of me figure out why it does this. Any  help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe your code runs more than once ...? Also, have you _verified_ what your session contains, or do you just _assume_ it was only this one entry? Do a var_dump of $_SESSION['cart'] before the loop.

Comment: Yes I've added alerts with window.alert tags to tell me what's going on and I only get one alert that says qty=1 and the loop stops, but my inventory is always reduced by double the quantity. I will try the var_dump though just to double check.

Comment: Don't use the _deprecated and insecure_ `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Here's the var_dump:`array(6) { ["id"]=> string(2) "73" ["qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["title"]=> string(15) "Product Summary" ["image"]=> string(34) "BCA_product_summary_2017_cover.jpg" ["category"]=> string(9) "Reference" ["type"]=> string(8) "Brochure" }`

Comment: How are you triggering this script? As @CBroe mentioned, maybe you're triggering it twice?

Comment: With a "check out" button that calls a submit.php page and uses the $_Session['cart'] vars to order the collateral materials.

Comment: Can you show that code as well, so we get a complete picture of the flow?

Comment: `<?php session_start();
$customer = $_POST['customer'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$details = $_POST['details'];
$delivery_date = $_POST['delivery_date'];
$delivery_location = $_POST['delivery_location'];

foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $result){ 
 $insert  = 'UPDATE collateral SET stock = stock - '.$result[qty].' WHERE id = '.$result['id'];
 mysqli_query($insert) or die(mysqli_error());
 }`

Comment: I would get 2 alerts if the code was running twice. I do not. After pasting the var dump, I'm thinking it has something to do with the fact that the qty is a string rather than an integer. ???

Comment: Please add your code to the question instead of in a comment. And this is not the code for the button you that triggers the submit.php. It shoud work just as well with a string, since you're concatenating the query.

Comment: `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="cart" action="submit.php">
                              <button class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" type="submit">Place Order</button>
                              </form>`

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this "question" thing so forgive me if I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is embarrassing but, the foreach statement somehow got pasted way down in the email code a second time and was in fact running twice. Thanks everybody. My bad.